# $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I understand that when we define $f(0,0) = 0$, There is no limit in $(0,0)$. For instance, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}~ f(x,x) \neq f(0,0)$  or with sequences,  $f(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$.

In the above I have used each time the fact that $f(0,0)$ was defined. 
My question is, what can be said when there is no value defined for $f(0,0)$ ?

Would the following work:
define $u_n = (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ and $v_n = (\frac{2}{n},\frac{1}{n})$. These two sequences have the same limit yet $f(u_n) = \frac{1}{2} \neq f(v_n) = \frac{2}{5}$, therefore the limit does not exist ?

Comment: Just to complement your assertion in your last paragraph: note that $f(r \cos\theta, r \sin \theta) = \cos \theta \sin \theta$. That is, the limit is indeed quite sensitive to the sequence chosen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard example
of a function that
does not have a limit
at a point.

A useful way of looking at this
is to set
$x = t^a, y=t^b$
and see what happens
for various values
of $a$ and $b$
as $t \to 0$.

Because of symmetry,
I will assume that
$a \le b$
so that
$c = b-a \ge 0$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}
&=\dfrac{t^at^b}{t^{2a}+t^{2b}}\\
&=\dfrac{t^{a+b}}{t^{2a}+t^{2b}}\\
&=\dfrac{t^{a+b-2a}}{t^{2a-2a}+t^{2b-2a}}\\
&=\dfrac{t^{c}}{1+t^{2c}}\\
&\to\dfrac12
\qquad\text{as } t \to 0\text{ if }c = 0\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } t \to 0\text{ if }c > 0\\
\end{array}
$

Try looking at
$\dfrac{x^uy^v}{x^r + y^s}
$
for various values
of the exponents
in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need a value defined at $f(0,0)$ to find this limit. If the limit is the same as the function evaluated at that point, we say this function is $\textbf{continuous}$ at that point.

Now to answer your question, the limit doesn't exist (and this has nothing to do with the value at $f(0,0)$). I think you already saw this by choosing two sequences that has different limits. Another way to see this is picking a trace where $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$. Eg. along the line $x = 0$, the limit is clearly $0$, and along the line $x=y$, the limit is $\frac 1 2$.